# How to change width of button element in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im rendering an array of views which i then render in a button group.
How do I change the width of the single button element?
Here im just changing the width of the view.

```
playerNumBtn = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightGreen', flex: 1, borderWidth: '50%', width: '50%', height: '100%', borderWidth: 1, }}>
            <Text># {this.state.players[i].number}</Text>
             </View>
          );
    }


rowofbuttons = [{ element: playerNumBtn },
          { element: playerNameBtn }, { element: onePointBtn },
          { element: twoPointBtn }, { element: threePointBtn },
        { element: assistBtn }, { element: reboundBtn },
        { element: stealBtn }, { element: blockBtn }, { element: foulBtn }]

<ButtonGroup style = {styles.buttonGroupStyle}
            buttons={rowofbuttons}
            underlayColor={'rgba(127, 220, 103, 1)'}
            selectMultiple
            selectedIndexes={this.state.selectedIndexes}
            onPress={selectedIndexes => {
              this.setState({ selectedIndexes });
            }}
            containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 0, marginTop:0 }}
          />

buttonGroupStyle: {
      marginTop: 0,
      marginBottom: 0,
  },
```

[image]

Comment: Like you just want to change the width of one of those boxes? Might need a bit of clarification. thx

Comment: see how the left column has just shrunk the border to 50%? but it hasn't made the whole column 50% (that is the element: playerNumBtn). this seems to be because ive created the view with a parent element, and the parent needs to be styled and given a width of 50%. but im unsure how to do that the way ive done it here because the parent is not a tagged syntax. In other words how do i style the playerNumBtn and not just the view it contains?

Comment: Ah, so you actually will not be able to. The parent will need to be the one controlling the width. So it depends on how ButtonGroup is laying out the elements. You could however make it to where the grid thing is not controlling and just let it conform to all the children. But you will have to make changes to what you have currently.

Comment: At the moment im just using react-native-easy-grid to render rows and the buttongroups make the rows. is there no way to style an individual button width within a ButtonGroup? otherwise i suppose i can just get rid of the buttongroups and just use buttons within easy-grid columns

Comment: Yeah, you may have to use columns and style each column individually. It's also not too hard to write custom code for a simple grid or column pattern.